# R Dplyr mutate new column by calculating from other columns with conditionally replaced values

Tags: r, dplyr

Given the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 x2 = c(5,4,3,2,1))
```

I would like to mutate a new column (x3) which is the sum of x1 and x2 columns.
However, I would like to conditionally replace the values before calculating such that:

```
1 = 0    
2 = 1   
3 = 2   
4 = 3   
5 = 3
```

This would result in the following mutated column:

```
x3 
3   
4   
4   
4   
3
```

My solution so far has involved mutating new x1 and x2 columns containing the replacement values before summing those and then dropping the mutated x1 and x2 but this seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, we can subtract 1 from the data, use `pmin` to restrict the value greater than 3 to 3 and get the `rowSums`

```
df$x3 <- rowSums(pmin(as.matrix(df-1), 3))
```

-output

```
> df
  x1 x2 x3
1  1  5  3
2  2  4  4
3  3  3  4
4  4  2  4
5  5  1  3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(, ~ifelse(. > 3, 3,. - 1), .names = "new_{.col}")) %>% 
  mutate(x3 = rowSums(.[3:4]))
```

```
   x1 x2 new_x1 new_x2 x3
1  1  5      0      3  3
2  2  4      1      3  4
3  3  3      2      2  4
4  4  2      3      1  4
5  5  1      3      0  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, in `base R`:

```r
z <- c(0, 1:3, 3)

df$x3 <- z[df$x1] + z[df$x2]
df

#>   x1 x2 x3
#> 1  1  5  3
#> 2  2  4  4
#> 3  3  3  4
#> 4  4  2  4
#> 5  5  1  3
```

---

Yet another `base R` solution:

```r
z <- c(0, 1:3, 3)

df$x3 <- rowSums(sapply(df, \(x) z[x]))
df

#>   x1 x2 x3
#> 1  1  5  3
#> 2  2  4  4
#> 3  3  3  4
#> 4  4  2  4
#> 5  5  1  3
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

z <- c(0, 1:3, 3)

df %>%
  mutate(x3 = rowSums(map_dfc(., ~ z[.x])))

#>   x1 x2 x3
#> 1  1  5  3
#> 2  2  4  4
#> 3  3  3  4
#> 4  4  2  4
#> 5  5  1  3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is a neat solution but in my actual data I have 13 columns to add and so indexing them manually isn't all that practical.

Comment: My new `tidyverse` solution does not need manual indexing, @r0bt!

Comment: And I have just added another base R solution that does not need manual indexing, @r0bt.